# Converting PDF to image with PDFBox results in strange characters (Font issue)

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I use PDFBox (2.X) to convert PDFs to images. The whole thing is is running under linux and previously I had some trouble converting certain PDFs with non-embedded fonts. Then I added the base-14 fonts to the system and everything worked. So far so good.

Now a PDF came in which uses Courier-Bold but the result is the following, although Courier-Bold is installed on the system. (Should be roman letters cause my russion is a bit rusty ;-):

[image]

So I am a bit puzzled why the PDF isn't converted correctly. The font in the PDF is defined as
`1 0 obj <</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Courier-Bold/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>`

So why isn't PDFBox isn't selecting the right font? There is no warning shown while converting the PDF. The following fonts are installed:

- Courier.ttf
- CourierBold.ttf
- CourierOblique.ttf
- Courierboldoblique.ttf

I also installed the additional fonts mentioned in the comments (`CourierNewPS-BoldMT,CourierNew-Bold,LiberationMono-Bold,NimbusMonL-Bold`) but neither worked.
Everytime I added a new font (to /.local/share/font) I get the message from PDFBox that a new font was found - so the font itself is recognized. It must be something else.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the PDF. It displays and converts to PNG images with callas pdfToolbox (caution, I'm affiliated with this tool) - PDF and images look identical (and are both German). The font is not embedded (which by itself is bad but allowed), but I can't see anything wrong with that definition either. Seems to point to a PDFBox specific issue (and I can't help further with that :))

Comment: On a windows system the conversion also works correctly - but windows brings some other fonts along...

Comment: I'm not surprised - looks like an encoding problem. Cause could either be the fonts (doubtful) or more probably I would say that PDFBox picks up a default encoding from the operating system and ignores what the font in the PDF is telling it (which is Win Ansi). If there are encoding settings in PDFBox, you could play with those. Or if it's possible to change the default in Linux to try whether that helps, it's probably a worthwhile try as well.

Comment: It works fine on my W10 with 2.0.21... The PDF is a very simple one. Are there any log messages? Does any of the following fonts exist on your system: "CourierNewPS-BoldMT", "CourierNew-Bold", "LiberationMono-Bold", "NimbusMonL-Bold"?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I added the log messages. (As mentioned in my other comment on windows it is working fine for me, too). None your mentioned font is on that system. Update: I added CourierPS, CourierNext but no difference...

Comment: Get some font inspection tool and look for the "Postscript name" in CourierBold.ttf . It should be one of the 4 I mentioned. If not, then tell what the name is. Maybe we'll have to add that one to the list. You can also get it with `new TTFParser().parse(new File("CourierBOLD.ttf")).getName()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The postscript name is "Courier-Bold" (the other are "Courier", "Courier-Oblique", "Courier-BoldOblique")

Comment: Oops, that one ("Courier-Bold") was in the list, I missed it. Please try replacing that font with a different one, e.g. LiberationMono-Bold.

Comment: If I look at the list (2.0.22-SNAPSHOT) I do not see it in there: `substitutes.put("Courier-Bold",
                Arrays.asList("CourierNewPS-BoldMT", "CourierNew-Bold", "LiberationMono-Bold",
                        "NimbusMonL-Bold"));`

Comment: And while your at it: Can you also add 'ZapfDingbatsITCbyBT-Regular' as an ZapfDingbats substitute? Thanks

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I added the substitution font myself but it didn't help. There are no related errors now. I also tried to to add LiberationSans and CourierNew and Nimbus but it also didn't help.

Comment: Did you remove the "Courier-Bold" font? That one is used first. If it isn't found, then the substitutes will be used. I'll have a look at the ZapfDingbats font later.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I removed the Courier-Bold font and now it is working?! Does it mean that the font is broken or faulty?

Comment: I think so. I can't find any other explanation. Lets blame it on Putin!

Comment: :-D yeah lets do that. If you add that as an answer I'll except it. If you don't have the time np I'll do it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause was related to the font itself. Currently, PDFBox expects either "Courier-Bold", or as substitutes, fonts with the name

- CourierNewPS-BoldMT
- CourierNew-Bold
- LiberationMono-Bold
- NimbusMonL-Bold

Removing the "Courier-Bold" font and adding one of the fonts above solved the problem. The most probable explanation is that the font was broken.

Comment: The font was this one: https://blogfonts.com/courier-bold-1.font  Maybe the problem was that it was converted from the windows/russ_font folder :-)